# How does Google get around the cross-site font-usage security in Firefox with their new Webfonts service?

Tags: security, font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts

Google offers webfonts - http://code.google.com/webfonts

They work in Firefox, but FF has a security policy to stop cross-site font usage - http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/beautiful-fonts-with-font-face/ (search for Cross-Site Font Usage).

Can anyone hazard a guess how they do this? Do they use 'access control headers'? Is there a way to test for it?

And are there any security concerns with adding access control headers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they use access control headers. You can use Live HTTP Headers to verify this:

1. Go to the page for a font, eg: http://code.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Droid+Sans
2. Click on "Use this font"
3. Go to the href in the HTML snippet, eg: http://code.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Droid+Sans
4. Enable Live HTTP Headers
5. Go to the src from the CSS that you pened in step 3. This will download the font and you can see that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is in the response headers.